# SASS grid system outer padding

Tags: html, css, sass

I've made this own fluid grid system in SASS, but there is a problem.

I've set the `padding-left` and `padding-right` both to `20px`, which is the gutter width (the space between each column).

Which is all working fine, but the first and the last `column` in a `row` sets the `padding` as well on the outer sides. This I want to prevent but I have no idea what calculation I have to make for that.

The grid currently looks like this: (the red spacing is what I want removed)

[image]

The code for the system looks like this:

```
@import "../../mixins/cross-browser-elements/_box";

$column-count: 12 !default;
$gutter-width-px: 20px !default;
    
@function calculate-column-width($index) {
  @if ($index > 0) {
    @return percentage($index / $column-count);
  }
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

  > .column {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: ($gutter-width-px / 2);
    padding-right: ($gutter-width-px / 2);
    @include box-sizing(border-box);


    @for $index from 1 through $column-count {
      &.size-#{$index} {
        width: calculate-column-width($index);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The thing I tried was just adding this piece of code:

```
&:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

&:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Under this piece of code

```
> .column {
    ......
```

But that just made the first and last column in that row a bit bigger on the left and right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add 20px negative margin to the left and right side on ".row"?

```
.row {
  margin: 0 -20px 20px;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) But why doesnt this work: `margin: 0 -$variablename 20px` its output is just wrong while i set the `$variablename` variable to a correct number in px's

Comment: If you want to use variables with a minus in front you need to write it like this: `-#{$variablename}`

Comment: Ah okay thanks, so then it would be: `margin: 0 -#{$variablename} 20px;`?

Answer (score 0):

You could add this extra lines to your mixin:

```
   ...
    @for $index from 1 through $column-count {
          &.size-#{$index} {
            width: calculate-column-width($index);

            &:nth-child(#{$column-count}n) { // Clear every last item padding-right
              padding-right: 0;
            }

            &:nth-child(1) { // Clear every first item padding-left
              padding-left: 0;
            }
          }
        }
...
```

An example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/da6c1a341d289b4f3b67

Comment: But that gives each column item a different `width`. So that's the same result as the code i had right?

Comment: @Dreiba hmm weird some boxes are 67px and some 66px let check it for a while :)

Comment: Per each 3 boxes they are 1px larger for some reason. But when i check it on other grid systems, its the same

Comment: @Dreiba I had set a max-width: 800 (800/12 = 66.6) if you change the max-width to 900px which 900/12 = 75 an integer number then each box are equal http://sassmeister.com/gist/da6c1a341d289b4f3b67

Comment: But the i dont want a 'fixed' layout xd. The thing i want is that i get rid of the spacing on the outer side of the edge columns

Comment: @Dreiba You could `round` your width to avoid this issue `width: round(calculate-column-width($index));` an example http://sassmeister.com/gist/da6c1a341d289b4f3b67 (you can have either a fixed or a fluid layout)

Comment: I really have no idea what you mean man.. With fluid i mean that it just fits the above container. In this case `row`. so it should fit the whole screen right?